# GetProcAddress, Error 127 (ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND)

Tags: c++, dll, ogg

I am trying to call a function defined in a DLL, documented here:

http://xiph.org/vorbis/doc/vorbisfile/ov_fopen.html

LoadLibraryA is successful and GetProcAddress seems to return a valid address for every other function I've tried it with. Here it returns NULL here and GetLastError() returns 127 (ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND).

```
const char* dllName = "libvorbisfile.dll";
mhDll = LoadLibraryA(dllName);
typedef int (__cdecl *OV_FOPEN)(char*, OggVorbis_File*);
OV_FOPEN ProcFOpen = (OV_FOPEN) GetProcAddress(mhDll, "ov_fopen");
```

What can I do?

Comment: Did you build that libvorbisfile.dll yourself or did you get it from somewhere else? In any case, [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) can tell you if the DLL really exports that function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this discussion thread](http://lists.xiph.org/pipermail/vorbis-dev/2008-December/019659.html), some versions of libvorbisfile.dll are missing ov_fopen.

Comment: I don't know where you found that thread but that seems to be the case here. I opened the dll in depends and the function is missing! :(

Comment: All I did was a web search for 'ov_fopen libvorbisfile' and boom there it was on the first page of results.

Answer (score 3):

Examine the DLL with [Depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and find out why you can't find the function.  It's probably either just the name is wrong in the documentation or there's a name mangling issue.